react-hook-form handleSubmit SubmitErrorHandler not working at all
I am trying to use the second parameter of handleSubmit to be an errorhandler in case there are errors in the form. But no matter how I try, if there's for example a required field in the form that doesn't have a value, the handleSubmit does not get triggered at all and there for the SubmitErrorHandler doesn't get triggered either.
If I fill in the required field, the handleSubmit gets called as expected.
<form onSubmit={formMethods.handleSubmit(onSubmit, onError)}> ... const onError: SubmitErrorHandler<any> = (error) => console.log(error); const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<any> = (data, event) => console.log(data); 

fairly sure required fields being omitted does not trigger form submission. if you would just like to run some js on the case the form is not valid you can use the invalid event. Alternatively you can remove the required attribute from fields and perform all the validation yourself and perhaps add some other visual indicator of requiredness.

managed to resolve this with the onInvalid event, thank you!
